# How to remove an object from a list in DynamoDB using Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to write a Lambda function to remove an object from a list in DynamoDB. In this case I am passing in `"author": "J.K. Rowling"`, `"title": "Harry Potter"`, and `"userid": "041c9004"` as parameters. I want to delete the matching object from the `books` list. What is the correct syntax for the UpdateExpression statement? There may be some other errors within `params{}` as well.

The DynamoDB table looks like this. userid is the primary key:

```
{
  "books": [
    {
      "author": "J.R.R. Tolkien",
      "title": "Lord of the Rings"
    },
    {
      "author": "J.K Rowling",
      "title": "Harry Potter"
    },
    {
      "author": "George RR Martin",
      "title": "A Song of Ice and Fire"
    }
  ],
  "isactive": true,
  "ispublic": true,
  "lastupdated": 1597690265,
  "userid": "041c9004"
}
```

Here is the Lambda function:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'us-east-1'});

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback){

    let params =  {
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":attrValue": [{ 
                "author": event.author,
                "title": event.title
            }]
        },
        ExpressionAttributeNames : {
            "#books" : "books"
        },
        Key: {
            userid: event.userid
        },
        TableName: 'Users',
        UpdateExpression: "REMOVE #books[:attrValue]", //this is incorrect
        ReturnValues:"ALL_NEW",
    };
 
    docClient.update(params, function(err,data){
        if(err) {
            callback(err, null)
        }else{
            callback(null, data)
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone is wondering, here is the full solution:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'us-east-1'});

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback){

    var params = {
        TableName: 'Users',
        Key: {
            userid: event.userid
        }
    };

    docClient.get(params, function(err, data){
        if(err) {
            callback(err,null);
        } else {
            var indexOfAuthor = data.Item.books.findIndex(i => i.author === event.author);
            console.log('The index of the author is ' + indexOfAuthor);
            var updateExpressionString = "REMOVE #books[" + indexOfAuthor + "]"
            
            let paramsdelete =  {
                ExpressionAttributeNames : {
                    "#books" : "books"
                },
                Key: {
                    userid: event.userid
                },
                TableName: 'Users',
                UpdateExpression: updateExpressionString,
                ReturnValues:"ALL_NEW",
            };
    
            docClient.update(paramsdelete, function(err,data){
                if(err) {
                    callback(err, null);
                }else{
                    callback(null, data);
                }
            });
            
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question!

Unfortunately, the `UpdateExpression` will only allow you to `REMOVE` from the list if you specify an index ([docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.Modifying.UpdateExpressions.DELETE)).

You'll need to read the item from the DB, find the indexes you want to remove, and `REMOVE` that specific index.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping it was possible without finding the index first, but that approach will work well